# Downcasting fails

Tags: swift, downcast

I encountered little unusual down casting failure.

I have a class `Vehicle` in `FrameworkA`

**FrameworkA**

```
open class Vehicle {
    open var name: String = ""
}
```

And I subclassed this `Vehicle` class in other project.

**Project**

```
import FrameworkA

class Car: Vehicle {
    var maker: String = ""
}
```

And I tried downcast like this

```
let vehicle = Vehicle()
let car = vehicle as! Car
```

If they are in same framework(or same project namespace), there is no problem, but in this case down casting from `Vehicle` to `Car` fails.

The error message was just like below.

```
Could not cast value of type 'FrameworkA.Vehicle' (0x1070e4238) to 'Project.Car' (0x10161c120).
```

So I had to use extension of `Vehicle` class and used associatedObject. Is there any way to subclass and downcast?

Comment: Update your question with the actual code causing the error and post the exact (not "somewhat") error.

Comment: Updated the error message. Code was exactly what it was.

Comment: Is your Vehicle class declared as public?

Comment: Which line exactly is giving the error?

Comment: @rmaddy Added the case. it happens exact line of down casting `as! Car`. if I use optional like `as? Car`, the `car` will be nil.

Comment: BTW - you state that if the two classes are in the same framework, the cast works fine. Are you sure about that? It's simply not possible for the code you posted.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. As you answered here it shouldn't work. I even tested it in playground and confirmed it doesn't work. However I have a app already in app store and works nicely which I believe there is same logic. I'll keep update as soon as I find how it is going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course your code fails. It has nothing to do with using a framework or not.

`Car` is a special kind of `Vehicle`. You are creating a `Vehicle` object. You then try to cast it to a `Car`. But it's not a `Car`. It's a `Vehicle`.

The following works:

```
let car = Car()
let vehicle: Vehicle = car
```

That's fine because you create a `Car` which is also a `Vehicle`.

You can also do this:

```
let vehicle: Vehicle = Car()
let car = vehicle as! Car
```

That works because even though `vehicle` is declared as a `Vehicle`, the object it is actually pointing to is a `Car`.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a downcast... `Car` is a `Vehicle`, but `Vehicle` isn't a `Car`.

Comment: Yes I did. I'm going to edit my question to show this.